# Makefile: Why this method of Automatically Generating Prerequisites works?

Tags: c++, unix, makefile, prerequisites

I am reading a Makefile, and I find a way of generating prerequisites automatically that is different of [this tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html). That method is as followed:

```
DEPFILES = $(SRCFILES:src/%.cpp=obj/%.d)

-include $(DEPFILES)

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp | obj
        @echo compiling $(@F) ...
        @$(CXX) -O3 -ggdb $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $(@) -MMD -MP $(<)

obj:
        @mkdir $@
```

I could figure out how gcc generates .d files, when I first execute `make` command, `-include $(DEPFILES)` will fail and `obj/%.o`target will be invoked and generate .d files. But my problem is: when I modify some source files and do `make` again, what will happen ? I think `-include $(DEPFILES)` will success and .d files are included in the makefile, so the `obj/%.o` target in .d files are included in the makefile, but in fact I have already defined `obj/%.o` target in the origin makefile, is it a conflict ?

I have done some experiments and find `obj/%.o` target in the origin makefile will be invoke (because `echo` command is executed) and the .d files will be updated if necessary. But why is it ? We need the target in .d file to know the dependency and why is it not invoked ?

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the `.d` files? They explain part of this. [This page](http://make.mad-scientist.net/autodep.html) might also be of some help to read.

Answer (score 2):

When you're setting up a Makefile, a line that is only a target and dependencies, with no instructions following it is just an additional dependency.  So, as an example:

```
a.o: a.cpp
   g++ -o $@ -c $+

a.o: a.h b.h
```

The first line says to build `a.o`, it depends on `a.cpp`, and then the instructions on how to build it.  The second `a.o` simply adds additional dependencies on `a.h` and `b.h`.  This is basically what the above mechanism is doing, as it defines a lot of additional dependency lines, but doesn't add any instructions.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I have another problem: what's the meaning of  `|`  in the command `obj/%.o: src/%.cpp | obj` and when the target of 'obj' will be invoked ? thx.

Comment: According to [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), the `|` means that it's an order-only dependency.  It means that `obj/%.o` depends on `obj`, but isn't rebuilt just because `obj` changes.  In this case, it'll make sure to create the `obj` directory using mkdir prior to attempting to write the objects into it